# Joomla CMS on packagist

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, packagist

Can I download joomla CMS from packagist? There is a lot of joomla packages there but no one seems to be the same as: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Joomla packages at Packagist are part of the Joomla Framework (see https://framework.joomla.org/) not the Joomla CMS "per se".
Joomla framework are a set of libraries, which are shipped with the CMS too, which allows you to develop PHP applications (both web and cli) using the same classes that you will be using in the CMS.